# java seems to choose the overloaded concrete type when getting an parameterized type

Tags: java, generics, types, overloading, parameterized

I have been stumbled into the following issue, where I have overloaded the method `doSomething()`, which takes a `Boolean` or an `Object` and I call `returnSomething()` and pass the return value into `doSomething()`, as the following snippet shows:

```
public class SomeService {
    public <T> T returnSomething() {
        return null;
    }

    public void doSomething(Boolean a) {
       System.out.println("Boolean");
    }

    public void doSomething(Object a) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeService someService = new SomeService();
        someService.doSomething(someService.returnSomething()); // prints Boolean
    }
}
```

When I run the code it invokes the `doSomething((Boolean))`.

As the return type of the `returnSomething()` is type erased to an `Object`, I would have expected that it would be invoking `doSomething((Object))` instead.

Does anyone know if this is as expected behavior that it invokes `doSomething((Boolean))` and not `doSomething((Object))`?

I tried to change the order of these two methods to see if that mattered but it didn't. I also tried to changed the `Boolean` parameter to an `Integer` instead and it did behave in the same manner i.e. it invokes the Non-object method.

As a bonus information I also found out if I add an additional method `doSomething((Integer))`:

- IntelliJ 14 return following error message: `cannot resolve method doSomething(java.lang.Object)`
- Eclipse Mars returns the following error message: `the method doMethod(Boolean) is ambiguous for the type SomeService`

If I alter the order of the definition of `doSomething((Integer))` and `doSomething((Boolean))` the error message also changes.

```
public class SomeService {
    public <T> T returnSomething() {
        return null;
    }

    public void doSomething(Boolean a) {
       System.out.println("Boolean");
    }

    public void doSomething(Integer a) {
       System.out.println("Integer");
    }

    public void doSomething(Object a) {
        System.out.println("object");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeService someService = new SomeService();
        someService.doSomething(someService.returnSomething()); // compilation error
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The reason of this behavior is because of the generic return type.**

```
public <T> T returnSomething() {
    return null;
}
```

will "return" whatever type is needed from the type system perspective and **will always choose the most specific type if that is possible**. That's why:

1. it will pick `Boolean` in the first example (`Boolean` is more specific type than `Object`)
2. will not compile in your second example (`Boolean` and `Integer` are not in the same type hierarchy and so none of them is more specific)